# How to remove image from browser cache

Tags: javascript, html, caching, webkit, qtwebkit

In my web app, I have a large collection of thumbnails, the user is able to select a thumbnail and client side recrop from the original image to recreate a new thumbnail.

That's fine, in my app, I just set the newly created image instantly to the image source, without reloading it from the server, and next to this, the new image is uploaded to the server. This is to ensure a very responsive feeling. The problem is that when to user refreshes the page, he sees the cached old version of the thumbnail.

I know I could use some image.jpg?sometimestamp to be sure the browser has to download a new version of the thumbnail, but as I said, the app needs to be very responsive, even on small &slow internet connections. (Thats why the app in itself is stored on the user's computer and not downloaded live. Only uploads, downloads and jsons are transitting)

The ideal solution would be to be able to tell the browser : remove this particular file from your cache : someurl.com/somefolder/image.jpg, so that the browser has to fetch it again when it needs it. is this possible and how?

So I'm not asking how not to cache files or how to force re-verification each call, I'm asking how I could remove some particular file from browser's cache.

ps: this can be a webkit-only solution as this is the only platform it is running on.(it is actually a qtwebkit on a Qt project.

Answer (score 4):

The function **window.URL.revokeObjectURL()** can solve your problem.

> The URL.revokeObjectURL() static method releases an existing object
>   URL which was previously created by calling
>   window.URL.createObjectURL().  Call this method when you've finished
>   using a object URL, in order to let the browser know it doesn't need
>   to keep the reference to the file any longer.

For details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.revokeObjectURL

Note that this is an *experimental* function with limited cross-browser support.

Comment: Seems to be available in all browsers now: https://caniuse.com/?search=revokeObjectURL --- Fro your link: "This feature is available in Web Workers". Can you post some example code of how to use it? ... Using `URL.revokeObjectURL(imgurl);` still keeps the image in the cache and the old version shows up with a page reload.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Append a `?[something_volatile]` to the request when you need to download it again, and you'll get the same effect. That method won't take away any of the snappiness if you *only change the appendage string when needed*.

Comment: yeah... basically instead of the ?timestamp... it'll be more like  ?version_tag.. which you can control.

Comment: I could indeed store a lastmodification time in the database and use this as the volatile part... that's 1 sql call but this is fast anyway. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necropost, but I think it could be helpful for others in the same situation:

When your upload is done, perform an AJAX get request with **[no-cache header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)**.

By specifing this in the REQUEST, you tell the browser to ignore cache and to perform a new request to server.

Assuming I have a cached image at `/images/jondoe.jpg`, it could be like this :

Code ([using Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)):

```
Axios.post('/upload/new-image', FormDataObject).then(() => { 
  Axios.get('/images/jondoe.jpg', {headers: {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}}).then(reloadPageFunction)
// Now you'll have a new image in your cache
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete) is useful for u, according to it, u can use below code :

```
caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
    cache.delete('/images/image.png').then(function(response) {
        someUIUpdateFunction();
    });
})
```

Comment: This is part of the Service Worker API and not a standard browser API.